# Losing my lower range

Tags: voice

As I get older the lower end of my voice is deteriorating. I can still sing as high as I always have but it's my lower range that isn't what it used to be. I also can't seem to make interval jumps like I once did. When I was 47 I was in an accident and had to have surgery. They put a breathing tube in me and after surgery my voice was hoarse. Since then the lower end of my range has been a problem. I haven't heard of voices going higher as you age.

Answer (score 1):

Nor have I.  Based on your description, the breathing tube is more likely the culprit, not your age. I'm 52 and have my low register intact! I have temporarily lost my low range because I've dried my vocal chords out (drinking coffee before I sing or speak - I do voiceovers as well! ) and this may also be why your low register isn't functioning, that said,   it really sounds like you may have some damage to your vocal chords, I'd suggest a ENT take a look down your throat, specifically your vocal chords to check for damage!